# Placeholders in symfony's url_for() helper function

Tags: symfony1, routes, helper

I'm working on an AJAXy autocomplete widget. I'm trying to create a symfony URL with a placeholder, which I can then pass to my Javascript, so that the JS can inject the ID of records it has retrieved via AJAX. For example:

```
$this->widgetSchema['sons_list'] = new ynWidgetAjaxAutocomplete(
  array(
    'item_url'        => url_for( 'person/edit?id=%' ),
    // OR 
    'item_url'        => url_for( 'person/%/edit' ),
  )
);
```

But neither of these works - I am looking for `/person/%25/edit`, but the first yields `/person/edit/action?id=%25` and the second yields `/person/%25/action`. It does work if I pass a placeholder of digits, but this seems like a narsty hack to me:

```
$this->widgetSchema['sons_list'] = new ynWidgetAjaxAutocomplete(
  array(
    'item_url'        => url_for( 'person/edit?id=999999999999' ),
  )
);
```

Anyone know a cleaner way? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem was that the auto-generated action was using `$this->getRoute()->getObject()`, but symfony wasn't able to resolve the URL to `sfDoctrineRoute` and was stuck with `sfRoute`, which doesn't have a `getObject()` method. I have now adjusted my action to retrieve the record based on the `id` parameter, and started using `url_for( 'person/edit' )`, appending `?id=123` in the JS, similar to **Darmen**. I am satisfied with this.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass only one parameter, you can probably use `url_for('person/edit?id=')` and then just append dynamic parameter with js.

**update**

Another way - how about replacing `%25` with js?

Comment: With your first suggestion, I get `/person//edit`. Appending ID and eliminating the extra slash makes it `/person/edit?id=123`, but `sfDoctrineRouteCollection` is (oddly) not able to parse that route. With the second suggestion, that would be fine; but I cannot get `url_for()` to work with any placeholder other than one that matches `/^\d+$/`.

Comment: Actually, I think I need to adjust my action, then I should be good... let me try...

Answer (score 0):

Good question!
Here is my solution (pass to url number and replace it it JS)

```
function preview_document(NODE, TREE_OBJ) {
  var url_to = '<?php echo url_for(sprintf('@document_preview?id=%s', '-999999'));?>';
  $.get(url_to.replace('-999999', $(NODE).attr('id').replace('phtml_', '')), function (data) {
    $('#document-viewer').html(data);
  });
}
```

Comment: that was what I was getting at with my second code block in the question; but it seemed a little odd to me, so I was interested to know if there was a more "normal-looking" solution. Thanks!